# Rewriting a double integral with complex exponential function

Tags: integration, trigonometry, exponential-function, characteristic-functions

Why can we write 
$$
\begin{align}
I_T  &=  \int_\mathbb{R}\int_{-T}^{T}\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}e^{itx}dtdF(x)\\ &=  \int_\mathbb{R}\left[\int_{-T}^{T}\frac{\sin(t(x-a))}{t}dt - \int_{-T}^{T}\frac{\sin(t(x-b))}{t}dt\right]dF(x)
\end{align}
$$
if we consider the addition theorems and symmetry properties of the circular functions?

Comment: I believe I have fixed your TeX code.   Please ensure that it is a correct representation of what you meant. :)

Comment: @anorton: You missed `\ ` before the `sin`. That's a cardinal sin. An inaccessible cardinal sin!

Comment: @Asaf. Aaahh! I've always wondered how people forget that `\ `... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}e^{itx} &= \frac{e^{it(x-a)}-e^{it(x-b)}}{it}\\
&= \frac{\cos\left( t(x-a)\right) - \cos \left(t(x-b)\right)}{it} + \frac{\sin \left(t(x-a)\right) - \sin \left(t(x-b)\right)}{t}
\end{align}$$

by the addition theorem for the exponential function and Euler's formula $e^{iz} = \cos z + i\sin z$.

The first term, $\frac{\cos\left( t(x-a)\right) - \cos \left(t(x-b)\right)}{it}$ is an odd function, so its integral over the symmetric interval $[-T,T]$ is zero, and we are left with the integral involving only the sine terms.